# Capture traffic from Android emulator to localhost?

Tags: android, android-emulator, fiddler

How can I capture traffic from the Android emulator to a local webserver? Can I use Fiddler?

Thanks!

Comment: does your Android emulator have a proxy server setting? If so, you can use Fiddler. If worst came to worst, you could use http://www.fiddler2.com/r/?reverseproxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out a way to capture the traffic thanks to EricLaws comment.

I had to use a reverseproxy and write a FiddlerScript rule. I added the following line

```
if (oSession.host.toLowerCase() == "10.0.2.2:8888") oSession.host = "localhost:8082";
```

in the OnBeforeRequest function.
In my Android code I'm using the address 10.0.2.2:8888 to reach localhost:8082. Works great!